# How can I create OAuth based login with Open AI api?

Tags: authentication, oauth, openai-api

I'm trying to build an app using GPT3 APIs and would like users to login to the app using OpenAI's credentials so as to use their account for GPT3 APIs requests, however there is no support for 3rd party login so far in Open AI's documentation. Anyone has ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Doubt it. You will need to set up your own app and proxy their request to your app account. I would advise against doing any tricky things (extracting tokens etc) because you don't want to be banned from accessing OpenAI's API.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned Open ai does not have an oauth API like Google (for example). The only idea that occurs to me is to ask the user for their Open ai Api key and make the requests through that key